# Aggregation Filter to Return a Specific Value from Multiple Arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this json response structure :

```
{
    "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87772",
    "selected_product": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
    "sign_in_label": {
        "value": "Sign In",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "Sign In"
            }
        ]
    },
    "have_account_label": {
        "value": "Already have an account",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "Already have an account"
            }
        ]
    },
    "sign_up_label": {
        "value": "Sign Up",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "Sign Up"
            }
        ]
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "value": "Simple Membership",
            "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "code": "en",
                    "value": "Simple Membership"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "Credit Card",
            "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87773",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "code": "en",
                    "value": "Credit Card"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "applying_label": {
        "value": "You're appliying for your",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "You're appliying for your"
            }
        ]
    },
    "carousel_data": [
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": {
                "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
                "translation": [
                    {
                        "code": "en",
                        "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": {
                "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
                "translation": [
                    {
                        "code": "en",
                        "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": {
                "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
                "translation": [
                    {
                        "code": "en",
                        "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to use mongoDB aggregation to convert this json to this json structure based on the translation code "en":

```
{
    "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87772",
    "selected_product": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
    "sign_in_label": "Sign In",
    "have_account_label": "Already have an account",
    "sign_up_label": "Sign Up",
    "products": [
        {
            "value": "Simple Membership",
            "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
        },
        {
            "value": "Credit Card",
            "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87773",
        }
    ],
    "applying_label": "You're appliying for your",
    "carousel_data": [
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": "Welcome to your digital banking"
        },
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": "Welcome to your digital banking"
        },
        {
            "image": "img1.png",
            "text": "Welcome to your digital banking"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried this pipeline but i'm stuck with the products and the carousel_data:

```
var pipeline = [
        {
            $project: {
                sign_in_label: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$sign_in_label.translation",
                        as: "sign_in_label",
                        cond: [{ $gte: [ "$sign_in_label.translation.code", "en" ] },
                            "$sign_in_label.translation.value",
                            false]
                    }
                },
                have_account_label: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$have_account_label.translation",
                        as: "have_account_label",
                        cond: [{ $gte: [ "$have_account_label.translation.code", "en" ] },
                            "$have_account_label.translation.value",
                            false]
                    }
                },
                sign_up_label: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$sign_up_label.translation",
                        as: "sign_up_label",
                        cond: [{ $gte: [ "$sign_up_label.translation.code", "en" ] },
                            "$sign_up_label.translation.value",
                            false]
                    }
                },
                applying_label: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$applying_label.translation",
                        as: "applying_label",
                        cond: [{ $gte: [ "$applying_label.translation.code", "en" ] },
                            "$applying_label.translation.value",
                            false]
                    }
                },
                carousel_data:{
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$carousel_data",
                        as: "carousel_data",
                        cond: [{ $gte: [ "$carousel_data.text.translation.code", "en" ] },
                            "$products.translation.value",
                            false]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$sign_in_label" },
        { $unwind: "$have_account_label"},
        { $unwind: "$sign_up_label"},
        { $unwind: "$applying_label"},
        { $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            sign_in_label: {
                $push: "$sign_in_label.value"
            },
            have_account_label: {
                $push: "$have_account_label.value"
            },
            sign_up_label: {
                $push: "$sign_up_label.value"
            },
            products: {
                $push: "$products"
            },
            applying_label: {
                $push: "$applying_label.value"
            },
            carousel_data:{
                $push: "$carousel_data"
            }
        }},

        { $unwind: "$sign_in_label" },
        { $unwind: "$have_account_label"},
        { $unwind: "$sign_up_label"},
        { $unwind: "$products"},
        { $unwind: "$applying_label"},
        { $unwind: "$carousel_data"}
    ];
```

Using this pipeline i have the following response:

```
{
"_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87772",
"sign_in_label": "Sign In",
"have_account_label": "Already have an account",
"sign_up_label": "Sign Up",
"products": [
    {
        "value": "Simple Membership",
        "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "Simple Membership"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "value": "Credit Card",
        "_id": "5947e320d0f00f1794c87773",
        "translation": [
            {
                "code": "en",
                "value": "Credit Card"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"applying_label": "You're appliying for your",
"carousel_data": [
    {
        "image": "img1.png",
        "text": {
            "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "code": "en",
                    "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "image": "img1.png",
        "text": {
            "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "code": "en",
                    "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "image": "img1.png",
        "text": {
            "value": "Welcome to your digital banking",
            "translation": [
                {
                    "code": "en",
                    "value": "Welcome to your digital banking"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

As I'm new to MongoDB I think my pipeline is wrong. can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started on the right track but there are some parts that are difficult to understand at first glace, so it's probably best to look at them by each of their functions.

Your whole process is really just a single [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) here, which is ideally what I presume you want and need to use coupled with a preceding [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for the specific document. As there is a "translation" in everything, then it's basically the same block of code for every field:

```
    "sign_in_label": { 
      "$ifNull": [ 
        { "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$sign_in_label.translation",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.code", "en" ] }
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.value"
          }},
          0
        ]}, 
        "$sign_in_label.value"
      ]
    },
```

Let's work inside out from the indentation:

- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) - Point's to the translation array and all we want is an "equality" [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) match for the language, here it's `"en"`. This returns the filtered array to:
- [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) - This takes the "filtered" content as input and basically returns the inner `"value"` for each matched array member, which then feeds to:
- [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) - Which takes our "filtered" and "mapped" array which we are only expecting to have **one** element, and takes the first element from the array, in order to feed:
- [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) - Which finally considers the value that was extracted from the "first" position of the "filtered" and "mapped" array. If this value was not found, then it would be `null`, and is replaced with the `"value"` property as a "default".

So that's how the whole thing is put together, with only a little difference for the `"products"` and `"carousel"` arrays, since they are arrays and we re-map the "inner" elements.

The full pipeline is therefore:

```
var pipeline = [
  { "$project": {
    "sign_in_label": { 
      "$ifNull": [ 
        { "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$sign_in_label.translation",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.code", "en" ] }
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.value"
          }},
          0
        ]}, 
        "$sign_in_label.value"
      ]
    },
    "have_account_label": { 
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$have_account_label.translation",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.code", "en" ] }
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.value"
          }},
          0
        ]},
        "$have_account_label.value"
      ]
    },
    "sign_up_label": { 
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$sign_up_label.translation",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.code", "en" ] }
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.value"
          }},
          0
        ]},
       "$sign_up_label.value"
      ]
    },
    "products": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$products",
        "as": "el",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$el._id",
          "value": {
            "$ifNull": [
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$el.translation",
                      "as": "t",
                      "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$t.code", "en" ] }
                     }
                   },
                   "as": "t",
                   "in": "$$t.value"
                }},
                0
              ]},
              "$$el.value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "applying_label": { 
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$applying_label.translation",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.code", "en" ] }
              }
            },
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.value"
          }},
          0
        ]},
        "$applying_label.value"
      ]
    },
    "carosel_data": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$carousel_data",
        "as": "el",
        "in": {
          "image": "$$el.image",
          "text": {
            "$ifNull": [
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$el.text.translation",
                      "as": "t",
                      "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$t.code", "en" ] }
                    }
                  },
                  "as": "t",
                  "in": "$$t.value"
                }},
                0
              ]},
              "$$el.text.value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
];
```

Which will provide the output:

```
{
        "_id" : "5947e320d0f00f1794c87772",
        "sign_in_label" : "Sign In",
        "have_account_label" : "Already have an account",
        "sign_up_label" : "Sign Up",
        "products" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5947e320d0f00f1794c87774",
                        "value" : "Simple Membership"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5947e320d0f00f1794c87773",
                        "value" : "Credit Card"
                }
        ],
        "applying_label" : "You're appliying for your",
        "carosel_data" : [
                {
                        "image" : "img1.png",
                        "text" : "Welcome to your digital banking"
                },
                {
                        "image" : "img1.png",
                        "text" : "Welcome to your digital banking"
                },
                {
                        "image" : "img1.png",
                        "text" : "Welcome to your digital banking"
                }
        ]
}
```